# Tried to create symlink to Sublime Text 2

Tags: linux

I am relatively new to linux so please be patient.

I just attempted to create a symlink to Sublime Text 2.

I can open Sublime Text 2 by typing

```
~/bin/sublime <filename>
```

however, simply typing

```
sublime <filename>
```

gives me a "sublime: command not found" error.
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you installed sublime in a 'bin' directory inside your home folder. This 'bin' directory is not in your path and your shell will not find sublime there.
There are several solutions for this problem but a simple one is to add the '~/bin' directory to your path.  To do this, just edit your file ~/.bashrc (suposing you are using bash) or ~/.profile (if you are using any other shell) and add the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Restart your shell or simply call

```
source .bashrc
```